# How to show all data according to particular item clicked in ListView to new Intent

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, android-intent

I want to show, data read from mysql to `setOnItemClickListener`. Like whatsapp, i want that data read from database only show in one line with (...) after each line ends and after click on any `listview` item, all data will print in new intent having textview.

My java code from fetching to show data in `listview`.

```
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                ListDrwaer();
                pdialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                pdialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Unreachable Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "Loading Content", "Please Wait...", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public void ListDrwaer() {
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        String str = "", str2 = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("works");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = (jsonChildNode.getString("name"));
                String username = jsonChildNode.getString("username");
                String password = jsonChildNode.getString("password");
                String details = jsonChildNode.getString("details");
                String outPut = "\n\nName: " + name + "\n\n" + "Username: " + username + "\n\n" + "Password: " + password + "\n\n" + "Details: " + details + "\n\n";
                dataList.add(createList("details", outPut));
            }
            Collections.reverse(dataList);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[]{"details"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createList(String key, String value) {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(key, value);
        return data;
    }
```

Here is `layout` file where i show all data in `listview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mr_robot.app_proj.Home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is layout file of new intent where i wanna show all data after particular item clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mr_robot.temp_proj.Show"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/list_tag"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 datalist, one contains the real data, and one contain some part of text (using substring and add (...)). you can display using the second one, but when it's clicked then u send the data from the real list

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
  {
        String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
        // your code using intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ShownActivity.class);
        // put your real data here
        intent.putExtra("keydata", datalist2[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

and then you can use String data = getIntent.getExtra("keydata"); in the next activity and show your data

Comment: ok I understand what you said. i'm noob and problem for me is, how i do that things? can you show me? i don't know how to show exact data in intent when click on particular item.

Comment: i'd used '**List<Map<String, String>> dataList;**' and its an error  **"Array type expected"**.